# Cleaning tin discoloration on copper/tin lid

Tags: equipment, cleaning, copper-cookware

I have a tin-lined copper sauce pan from Rameria Mazzetti, which I love, but I notice the tin discoloring. I have read that it is normal that the tin becomes dull/gray when you cook in it.

My question concerns the lid: it has gotten some weird brown patterns after cooking with it a couple of times. Is this normal? Can it be cleaned without damaging the tin layer? A wipe with a sponge and soap doesn't do anything.

[image: Photo of the lid in question]

Comment: Well if you ever need to *re*-tin it some day:   http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Hand-Wiped-Tinning-of-Old-Copper-PotsPans-Inst/. Also they mention Bar Keeper's Friend and Wright's Silver Cream in the care section at the end. No experience, myself.

Comment: It's strange that this happened to your lid. I would have assumed this came from cooking at too high of a heat, but then the oan would also be discolored. What caused the tin lid to be discolored but not the pan?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can clean the copper and the tin with some tamarind, it is a trick we use in our home to clean the copper and brass vessels and they come out to be very clean. Your may notice discoloration again in some 20 or 30 days after cleaning but then you can clean it again! 
Just wet the cleaning surface with some water and apply tamarind or simple tamarind paste to it, then simply scrub it with a normal scrubber and  wash it.